# Communicating image data between Python and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, database

I'm currently working to send image data, in the form the byte arrays, from Python to JavaScript. I tried to use Redis as a means of in-memory, persistent communication channel, but it seems like bad design to force users to separately run `redis-cli` in the terminal. I tried to see if I can launch a Redis server using Python, but I could not find anything for that either. Is there an efficient, user-friendly way of setting up this type of communication? Would socket programming be a good way of setting up this communication channel as well?

Comment: Why not use existing standards?  For instance, both Python and Javascript can read `.png` files.

Comment: 1) I want to manipulate images in Python and send that to JavaScript and 2) I don't want to store the intermediate images on disk just to be read by JavaScript. With these constraints, I definitely need a direct communication channel. But please feel free to let me know if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I decided to go down the path of using websockets to achieve bidirectional communication between Python and JavaScript. Specifically, I set up a websocket using [tornado](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado), setup Python and JavaScript cilents, and communicate via event-driven programming.

I really wanted to steer away from calling `redis-cli` or any other bash commands via subprocess, and I think using websockets is an elegant and efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can start redis-cli from your python code using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). As per my understanding of your problem, you have to use subprocess.Popen(), to run a terminal command in a separate thread(in parallel). If want your python code to wait for the terminal command to finish, you can use subprocess.call()

Comment: Hi Muhammad, I did think about doing this, but it didn't seem like good practice and I thought it might get muddy with executing command line under the hood. Do you know of any examples where a library executes commands to launch servers or anything similar in spirit?

Comment: Sounds good but as per your constraints I think you have to do that. Otherwise you have to store the intermediate result to the disk as suggested by @Paul

Comment: I just want to explore all my options before I resort to just calling `redis-cli` via subprocess. Is socket programming a valid way of accomplishing my goal with my specific constraints?

Comment: Okay! Then wait for the experts to let you know some better options :)